# Full text search constain multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, contains

I'm using full text search with SQL Server 2008. I want to search in 2 columns with different criteria.

Example:

- column name : contains(name,'"ma*"')
- column address : contains (address, 'tr')

When I use `OR` operator like this:

```
contains(name, '"ma*"') or contains (address, 'tr')
```

it becomes very slow. Is there any other solution to combine them in one request? Thanks in advance

Comment: How fast was it before?  How fast is it now?  Full text searches will almost always be slow because it requires a full table scan except in very rare circumstances.

Comment: i used LIKE , but it was very slow , it make 9 secondes to select 500000 row , so i decided to use full text search , but i don't know how . using contains(name,'"ma*"') or contains (address, 'tr') ; it make more than 14 secondes

Comment: Do you have a [fulltext index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) on both of the columns you're searching?

Comment: Do you really need placeholders in your search? It's hard to tell from your examples. In case of doubt, you might want to provide more detailed search patterns, and sample data. Did you try `CHARINDEX`? If the individual queries were *much* faster, you could consider to run them separately and `UNION ALL` their results.